# How to fix "Error: Unable to access jarfile" on MacOS?

Tags: java, ventura

On MacOS Ventura (13.3.1) I am trying to run a jar file

```
java -jar somefile.jar
```

and get the error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile somefile.jar
```

Having looked for how to solve this it seems I have to give "Full Disk access" to "Java". I found some answers with some links to some various locations, none of them do exist.

So how to solve this problem? What EXACT file do I have to give full disk access for MacOS Ventura and java version 1.8.0_371 (or how to figure that out)?

I tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141180/mac-os-x-10-6-7-java-path-current-jdk-confusing) and [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592466/not-able-to-access-jarfile-on-desktop-in-macos-11):

1. `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` -> `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` is greyed out, unable to select it:
   [image]
2. `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/` -> Path does not exist (no "Java" under "Library")
3. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home` -> Folder under "JavaVirtualMachines" is empty...

I installed java following the instructions given in [HERE](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.html).

Comment: What path does running `/usr/libexec/java_home` give you?

Comment: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

Comment: You may reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70592466/not-able-to-access-jarfile-on-desktop-in-macos-11

Comment: added the reference  ...

Comment: Hmm, java_home should return something like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`, the plugin is for browsers and may not even be installed any longer. How did you install Java?

Comment: I followed these instructions: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must go to Security & Privacy in Settings --> Privacy --> Full Disk Access. Then give your jar file access there. For more info, go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469536/why-does-a-jar-file-have-no-permissions-to-read-from-disk-when-started-via-doubl

Comment: Now I get an error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/bluecolored/bluemap/cli/BlueMapCLI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` I guess I have to update java? How to do that IN THE MOST SIMPLE WAY POSSIBLE???

Comment: This article explains it quite simply: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.html